# How to exit full-screen mode if Ctrl-Shift-Alt F key does not work?

Tags: vnc, fullscreen, mobaxterm, tightvnc, vnc-viewer

I'm using a cloud service through SSH jump host using MobaXterm. After login, in the command line, I start vncserver using the command

```
vncserver -localhost no -geometry 3840x2160 :5
```

and connect to a VNC session successfully in MobaXterm.

There is a "Fullscreen" toolbutton right below the tab of VNC session. So I click it and the Ubuntu really switches to full-screen mode. Then I want to exit the full-screen mode of Ubuntu. I heard from somewhere that short-cut key `Ctrl-Shift-Alt F` can do this job, so I pressed `Ctrl-Shift-Alt F`, several times. But, it doesn't exit; there is no response at all! I also tried to open Windows Task Manager to kill vncviewer or MobaXterm, but Task Manager cannot be opened. Though I can press Alt-Tab key to show applications running in the Windows system, I cannot switch to any of them.

Finally, I opened a terminal in Ubuntu and run `vncserver -kill :5` which brought me back to the Ubuntu command line and thus exited the full-screen mode of Ubuntu GUI. But, that's an awkward abnormal way of exit. Is there any elegant way to exit full-screen of VNC in MobaXterm? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Move the mouse on the top of the screen and you should see (eventually) button to exit full screen mode
2. Press Alt+space and you should see menu to move, resize, minimize, maximize the current window